# How to make the 3D extrusion smooth in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I'm trying to make a **rounded** 3D cube in photoshop:

[image]

The right one is what i wanted to replicate in Photoshop, the left one is what i could do using the 3D feature in Photoshop (3D -> New extrusion 3D from layer).

How can i make the corners of the cube rounded, like the right one?

Comment: You can not. Photoshop is not a 3D editing application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the extruded object already in PS and it's rasterized, you can continue there. This receipe is useless for vector objects.

Make a couple of copies of the object without any background. Add a layer which has a color which do not fight with the object:

[image]

Merge one of the copies and the new background

[image]

Apply Gaussian blur

[image]

Select the emptiness around the copy and refine the edge to good shape:

[image]

Use the selection in the blurred layer to kill the background

[image]

DONE